# Migration from VS2003 to latest versions

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mfc, migration, activex, visual-studio-2003

I have a C++ MFC project that was created and built on visual studio 2003. I want to apply modifications on the software. I tried to open it with visual studio 2013 but a lot of dependencies are not fulfilled. If I recompile it with VS2013 will it still be working ?

Is it even possible to migrate the project from 2003 to the latest versions ? If so what do I have to do ?

Comment: That is way too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. Regardless, a few hints: If you're going to upgrade, pick at least VS2015. That gets you [ABI compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017) across 2015 through 2022. Upgrading should be possible, with one caveat: Static libraries. Prior to VS2015 those are strictly platform toolset specific. To upgrade, you'll have to recompile static libraries, if you have the source available. If you don't, then there's not much you can do.

Comment: Thank you @IInspectable . I know my question is too broad. I'm quite lost so I need informations to understand things more. Can I ask you where are static libraries located ?

Comment: Static libraries can be located anywhere your build configuration would look for them. They generally have a file extension of .lib. That file extension is also used with import libraries for DLLs. Though, giving it another though, even DLLs are subject to the same ABI incompatibilities, so you would have to recompile them, too. The linker settings in the VS project(s) should give you all the information you need to determine all of your dependencies.

Comment: @user18491635 you should post the error log, or at least the first 15-20 lines of it, so we can have an idea of what could be wrong.

Comment: @user18491635 I have sources of a software that my workplace use in their production. They want to be able to modify the software. I don't know what to do now. I need to discuss with everyone in order to see things more clearly. Exemple of errors : I want to open a dialog I get "14 ActiveX controls could not be installed. reinstall or register the controls and try again."

Comment: That means that you can actually compile the code without errors and run it. In that case it sounds like the error messages already tells you what the problem is. This is frequently the result of compiling for an architecture where you do not ship the respective ActiveX controls for (say, if you switched to an x64 build from an x86 build).